# AWS: Cannot access Webmin (Tomcat + Java + MySQL + Webmin AMI)

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, webmin

I've just launched a new AWS EC2 (t2.medium) build with the image "Tomcat + Java + MySQL + Webmin" Package Powered by SAIN3 (HVM)" . 
I've created this security group:

[image]

When I access public_IP:8080 I can see the Tomcat, but when I access public_IP:10000 (Webmin) I've got a **ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED**
and the instructions are clear: Webmin. `http:// <public DNS>:10000`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Webmin is not started by default.``ssh` into the machine and

Check:

```
service webmin status
```

If it is not running, start it by:

```
service webmin start
```

See: [Starting Webmin](https://help.webcontrolcenter.com/kb/a993/starting-webmin.aspx) automatically